# How to reset all package from PPA?

Tags: 12.04, ppa

I am getting an error `Failed to download repository information`. I want to reset all packages from `PPA` and want download the standard versions released for my distribution 12.04. What can I do?

Comment: Does it also say there is no internet connection?

Comment: Sounds like they did a dist-upgrade with a PPA enabled that doesn't have a the newer release built.

Comment: What PPA repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ppa-purge` can solve your problem
First, install it (if not already installed) :

> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

second, use it to purge the ppa and revert all the packages from it to their ubuntu versions :
usage:

> sudo ppa-purge ppa:repository-name/subdirectory

example :
if i want to revert all the packages installed from `ppa:blueman/ppa/`

> sudo ppa-purge ppa:blueman/ppa/

P.S the purging process may take several minutes so be patient

Comment: would you please elaborate the 2nd one? I totally failed to understand it.

Comment: http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/